# Laravel - Assert json array ids using wildcard

Tags: php, laravel

In my application I have a response like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "field": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "field": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to test the content of `items` and validate each `id`.

I've tried many solutions but no one works, for example (this is just a kind of pseudo-code):

```
assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
    $json->where('items.*.id', [10, 20])
)
```

Is there a way to use a wildcard to pick every ID and validate using an array?

Comment: Is this PHPUnit?

Comment: I'm using Pest, but is built on top of PHP unit so i can use both. This syntaxt come from Laravel HTTP fluent json testing anyway

Comment: Any feedback?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```php
$idArray = [10, 20];

$myObj = json_decode($json); // Turn JSON to obj
$items = $myObj["items"]; // Get items from object

// Filter the items for items that aren't in the ID list
$invalidItems = array_filter($items, function ($el) {
    // If the item has an id which isn't in the array, return true
    return !in_array($el["id"], $idArray);
});

// This returns true if we found 0 items with IDs not in the ID list
return $invalidItems == [];
```

You can similarly use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to simplify your array, then compare it to your ID array:

```php
$myObj = json_decode($json); // Turn JSON to obj
$items = $myObj["items"]; // Get items from object

$outIdArray = array_map(function($el) {
    return $el["id"];
}, $items);

// Compare $outIdArray to [10, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not tested yet* but below should work.

We attach an [`each`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Testing/Fluent/AssertableJson.html#method_each) on each child element under `items` and add a callback to [`where`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Testing/Fluent/AssertableJson.html#method_where) on that `id` key of each child.

```
<?php

assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
    $json->each('items', fn (AssertableJson $childJson) => 
                $childJson->where('id', fn($idVal) => 
                        in_array($idVal, [10,20])
                    )
        )
)
```